# XAMPP goes to index.php three times before output?

Tags: php, session, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a secure connection in my CMS by saving a generated token inside my $SESSION variable in PHP, while I echo the other part into a script tag that stores the token clientside. Whenever I do a request to the index.php, the generated gets renewed and echo'd onto the page.

The problem I was facing is that I generate and update my $SESSION variable 3 times, while only echoing the script tag once.

Firstly I thought it was because of a fault in my code. I walk through every line in my template file with PHP to get certain tags. When these tags are found, I echo some data from the database.

I have created a function called 'toLogfile' that uses file_put_contents and thus logs a line of text to a file in a folder of my XAMPP server.

I kept on logging backwards, to find the culprit and eventually got all the way back into my index.php.
All this file does is include some class-files and then execute the 'start_app' function which generates my page.

The logging still happens three times on the index.php, when I only F5 in Chrome once.
I am using the mod_rewrite module of the Apache server.

Is there any explanation WHY the entire function is called three times when I request the page only once?
I have been searching for this bug for like 2 hours now and in my knowledge I cant think of a solution?

Logging from the file from only one 'run':

```
2016-04-07 21:28:23 | index.php | 'data' = START APP!
2016-04-07 21:28:23 | page_controll.php | 'data' = PAGE PARSER SESSION SECURITY TOKEN: 5706b4d79766a
2016-04-07 21:28:23 | index.php | 'data' = APP DONE!
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | index.php | 'data' = START APP!
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | page_controll.php | 'data' = PAGE PARSER SESSION SECURITY TOKEN: 5706b4d883dc2
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | index.php | 'data' = APP DONE!
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | index.php | 'data' = START APP!
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | page_controll.php | 'data' = PAGE PARSER SESSION SECURITY TOKEN: 5706b4d8a84c1
2016-04-07 21:28:24 | index.php | 'data' = APP DONE!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long search, it appears to happen because of some empty icon link tags in my template:

```
<link id="favicon_shortcut_tag" rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
<link id="favicon_tag" rel="icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
```

This was causing the browser to do multiple requests to the same url.

Of course very logical, but finding it was pretty hard -,-